# For $[a]_n$ in $\Bbb Z_n$, what is the order of an invertible element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

So far I know that if $$[a]_n[b]_n = [1]_n$$ for some congruence class $[b]_n$, then $[a]_n$ is an invertible element of $\Bbb Z_n$.

Also for the definition of an order: Let $\sigma$ be in $S_n$. The least positive integer $m$ such that $(\sigma)^m = (1)$ is called the order of $\sigma$.

So does this mean that the order is infinite?
I can't seem to put these two together.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's Theorem, we know that

$$a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

whenever $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, and where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. In the language of congruence classes, this means that

$$[a]_n [a^{\varphi(n) - 1}]_n = [1]_n$$

Now an element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd{(a, n)} = 1$ (prove this!), so the order of any invertible element can't be bigger than $\varphi(n)$. In particular, it's very finite (more generally, in *any* finite group, every element has finite order).

Comment: I never thought about using Euler's Theorem but now I can see it.  I have a test coming up soon and my knowledge on Euler's totient function is very lacking.  I'm going to work on some more examples similar to this.  Thank you very much for your quick response.